# Pushing a UITableViewController onto a navigation stack fails

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with a `UITabBarController`, a few `UINavigationController` nested in it, and subclasses of `UITableViewController` inside those navigation controllers. When I try to push a newly created `UITableViewController` onto an existing navigation controller with an existing tableView in it, the app hangs, and Instruments shows that it keeps allocating something, over and over again, with a call to `[UIWindow _subtreeMonitorsForView:]`, whatever that is.

I'm pushing the controller in a very simple way, just:

```
_orderForm = [[OrderFormViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_orderForm animated:YES];
```

If I change it so that I push a plain `UIViewController` instead of a table, it works just fine. That is, if I just change the declaration in the OrderFormViewController.h file from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController` and it shows me the blank view, no hanging. What could be the problem?

Note, the content of OrderFormViewController.h is very bare bones, contains just the standard built in functions. I tried pushing a different subclass of `UITableViewController` (which works fine when used to initialize a `UINavigationController`) and the result is the same - app hangs and keeps eating memory.

Comment: do you have to push it?  How about using method presentModalViewController?

Comment: both `pushViewController` and `presentViewController` produce the same results, actually

Comment: Are you using xibs or storyboard?

Comment: all controllers are created programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the culprit to this and a couple of other similarly acting bugs. It was the fact that I doing this in my app delegate before instantiating my controllers:

```
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:bg];
```

Something about using `[UITableView appearance]` just does not play well with the code down the line, including being unable to use `UIDatePicker` in any variation (though `UIPickerView` still worked, which only confused me further).

For some reason the whole `UIAppearance` protocol, as promising as it sounds, is having some issues, this is not the first time I found it to be the cause of some odd bugs. Getting rid of it makes everything work perfectly.

Comment: I was stuck in it for past 5 hours. I had all the appeareance proxy defined in AppDelegate and the moment I commented it out, everything else worked like a charm !